# DirectorySearcher.FindAll() sometimes works, sometimes not

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I am trying to get a list of users from Active Directory. Basic search filter is:

```
objectCategory=person  
objectClass=user  
name=*'username'*
```

This is the code:

```
public static List<User> GetByUserName(string userName)
{
    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher();
    List<User> userList = new List<User>();
    try
    {
        ds.SearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://domain","user_name", "password");
        ds.Filter = "(|(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(name=*" + userName + "*)))";
        ds.PropertyNamesOnly = true;
        ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
        ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
        ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
        ds.Sort = new SortOption("name", SortDirection.Ascending);    
        foreach (SearchResult sr in ds.FindAll())
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
            User newUser = new User();
            newUser.Name = de.Name.Substring(3);
            newUser.AccountName = (string)de.Properties["samaccountname"].Value ?? " <Undefined>";
            newUser.EmailAddress = (string)de.Properties["mail"].Value ?? "<Undefined>";
            userList.Add(newUser);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("There was a problem search the Active Directory: " + ex.Message);
    }   
    return userList;
}
```

Problem is, that sometimes I get results, but sometimes not for the same userName. It's very weird.
When it's working I got results in 10-15 seconds.
But sometimes it's searching for 120s and then I received a timeout. Or earlier if I set ServerTimeLimit.
I don't know why it is sometimes working fine and why sometimes not. It seems random.
Is a problem in a code or somewhere else?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Is "domain" from "LDAP://domain" isn't really your domain DNS name ?

Comment: The wrapped OR brackets (`(|...)`) aren't necessary.

Comment: LDAP connection is good, I tested it. Problem is that tree nodes in AD is very huge with a lot of OU.

Comment: @Brian - thanks, you're right. But it did not resolve the problem.

Comment: When it doesn't work, what is ex.Message?  What do you mean, not the same userName?

Comment: I am having same issue, it gets stuck at FindAll method. no exception no error raised.